# InnoSetup: FileSize

Tags: inno-setup

I need to get size of File. I need to check if file more then 100b example:

```
If FileSize('C:\Program Files\MyProgramm\MyApp.exe') > 100 
   then
     msgbox ('File more then 100', mbinformation,mb_ok)
   else 
     msgbox ('File less then 100', mbinformation,mb_ok)
```

I look [function FileSize(const Name: String; var Size: Integer): Boolean;](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesize) , but it's work only if I need check -  size correct or not. But I cann't check on more or less

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the issue. Your call of the `FileSize` function is invalid. You need a variable of type `Integer` which will receive the size. So, are you asking how to call that function, or you have some issue with its result ?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I need example how to wok with function or any other variant. 
I need check is file0 bytes or more? That is all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var` keyword in the function prototype means that you need to declare a variable of the given type and pass it to the function. That variable then receives the value. Here is an example with the `FileSize` function:

```
var
  Size: Integer;
begin
  // the second parameter of the FileSize function is defined as 'var Size: Integer',
  // so we need to pass there a variable of type Integer, which is the Size variable
  // declared above
  if FileSize('C:\TheFile.any', Size) then
  begin
    if Size > 100 then
      MsgBox('The file is bigger than 100B in size.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else
      MsgBox('The file is smaller than 100B in size.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end
  else
    MsgBox('Reading the file size failed.', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Anyway, you may consider [accepting this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) if it resolved your question (that's what you can change at any time). Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!